# Need a link to last page of pagination

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

So im using regular pagination

```
previous_posts_link('<');  // using previous icon like this couse of easyer styling
echo paginate_links( $args ) ;
global $wp_query;
$big = 999999999;
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'    => __(''),
    'next_text'    => __(''),
    'mid_size'     => 2
) );
next_posts_link('>');     // using next icon like this couse of easyer styling
```

so my pagination looks looks something like this, it has next and previous icons and page numbers:

> < 1 2 3 >

i also need to have possibility of going to first page and last page of pagination with these 2 icons

> << and >>

so i figured out how to go to first page of pagination, since its on my index page i would just link these two icons: << with this:

```
bloginfo('wpurl');
```

so my question is how do i go to the last page of pagination? fkors my pagination should look like this:

> <<  < 1 2 3 >  >>

Comment: Any reason why you don't use an established plugin such as wp_pagination? Seems to me you're reinventing the wheel a little bit.

Comment: I tryed but i could not get it to work for on my site (3.6.1), thats why i have to do it this way... unfortunatly

Answer (score -1):

there r prebuilt wordpress function that calls the next and last page links

Comment: coul you plz give me a link so i can check it out?